# How can I see my MySQL database in Django admin site?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I am developing a Django application and I have created a MySQL database (I am using **Laragon** to manage it) and connected it with the App. I am using the database for another Python script that inserts data in the database too. What I want it to see all the database data in my Django admin site, but for some reason, I can't manage to do it? Do I have to add the tables to the Django models? or what should I do?

My settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'nlpwords',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': 3306,
}
```

}

[image]

I am using that database that has some data in some of the tables, but when I enter localhost/admin in my Django app I can't manage to see all those tables. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see your Django apps in your admin portal, you need to **register them in admin.py**.

Example:

```py
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.register(ModelName)
```

*Note: if you just made a new app and recently created models, make sure to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` so it gets registered to the db first.*

Comment: Okay but, I mean, the database is already created with some data in it. Is there a way to import those tables as models or something to see the same data in Django admin site?

Comment: you mean you want to see the data be displayed when you go to /admin right?

Comment: yes thanks, I am going to close the question, I finally managed to do it, thank you so much!

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: @enekovalero, how did you do it? Can you please post the solution you use?